# Как сделать перенаправление домена без www?

Tags: dns

DNS-записи:

```
$TTL    1800
@       IN  SOA NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.   hostmaster.www.site.ru. (
            1382970575 ; last update: 2013-10-28 14:29:35 UTC
            3600 ; refresh
            900 ; retry
            1209600 ; expire
            1800 ; ttl
            )
             IN      NS      NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
                     NS      NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
                     NS      NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
            MX 10   mx.yandex.ru.
@   IN A    144.182.154.63
@   TXT v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.ru
```

Прописать site.ru CNAME www.site.ru. верный шаг?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось в  Digitalocean при создании дроплета, создании DNS и тд лучше прописывать site.ru а не www.site.ru.